# TinyMCE moveable button in the content

Tags: tinymce

Is there any way to make mouse moveable button element in the editable content? If I insert a simple `<button>text</button>` element, it will be can't moveable.

Comment: I don't understand your question: do you just want to make a regular HTML `button` element be movable, or are you trying to do something specifically with the TinyMCE editor? If you just want a HTML button that can be moved around using the mouse, check out this code example (with comments): https://www.mediafire.com/file/esi23aeul6p72xk/movableButton.html/file